# How to set homepage using script

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

Look at the below screen shot

[image]

How to let a website take the control over client's browser to change the Home page?

Can this be possible using Java Scripts? I am using ASP.NET/C#. How to change clients Home Page in the above method?

Comment: This is *not* a thing you should be doing to unsuspecting users, just to be clear. Setting the user's homepage for them is pretty evil.

Comment: The example provided in the screenshot isn't automatically setting the homepage, it's asking the visitor if they _want_ to change their homepage. That doesn't seem evil to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for IE

```
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Make This Site Your Home Page" onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'; this.setHomePage('http://microsoft.com');">
</FORM>
```

Comment: For what version of IE? Microsoft doesn't actually allow this, do they?

Comment: Wow, Microsoft. Disgusting. Well, it won't work on any non-shitty browsers at least.

Comment: @nomulous - The user's screen shot resembles IE. So, I gave him code for IE. And for your kind information I have working codes for all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply forget about doing this with javascript. You will be wasting your time.

Comment: Then?? What's another way to do it?

Comment: <p>Please make our page your homepage</p>

Comment: @Gareth - I don't think this will benefit me much, as user friendliness is very important.

Comment: @meutex, you could ask your users to install some desktop application on their computers that would do this. If you have a single browser to support this application might be more or less easy to write but if you wanted to support all the browsers out there it could much more difficult and challenging task. So, as I said, there are so many other great things that you could do with ASP.NET and javascript, don't waste your time with things that you CANNOT do.

Comment: @Darin -- Nice answer. I am just trying to know the basic logic that's it for knowledge purpose.

Answer (score -1):

For obvious security reasons, you can't set the user's homepage with Javascript. Just ask them to do it themselves.

Comment: I am asking how Google implemented it? Not for security reasons.